# What is the input error here? And how do I connect via IP

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple echo server so that I can get the basics down but the code doesn't run properly. It prompts the port but then the scanner (Keyboard) wigs out. You can perpetually hit enter without any errors breaking the program. I've had this problem before but I forgot how I fixed it then.

Additionally, I've been having trouble creating the client socket with an Inet4Address. I continually get a mismatch error saying that the numbers in the IP are too large. Any help is much appreciated

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("PORT: ");
        int port = Keyboard.nextInt();
        Service = new ServerSocket(port);
        ClientSocket = Service.accept();
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocket.getInputStream()));
        output = new PrintStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println(Service.getInetAddress());
        while(true)
        {
            line = input.readLine();
            output.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

in the client side:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)   //taking in the IP in byte parts
    {
        System.out.println("IP PART " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        ip[i] = Byte.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.println("PORT: ");                                                          
    int port = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Comment: Variable names in Java should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks Stephen but that's not helpful at all

Comment: It is intended helpful.  If you learn to follow the Java style conventions you will find that people are more likely to treat your attempts at Java coding with respect.  Of course, you can ignore this ... and suffer the consequences.

Comment: It's true that convention dictates variables be started with a lowercase letter; however, I hardly see the use in strictly adhering to pedantic rulings on a piece of code that will never see use outside of my personal learning. Essentially, aside from confining to convention for convention's sake, there is no reason to be so strict. But I appreciate your input.

Comment: Thank you even though you weren't really much help

Comment: So I believe that I've fixed the server side. The problem was that it was waiting for the client to connect. Now I just need help inputting the IP in the client's side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the error you're getting in your client is something like this:

```
IP PART 1 :
192
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"192" Radix:10
        at java.lang.Byte.parseByte(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Byte.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at Client.main(Client.java:12)
```

The reason you're getting this error is that in Java, `byte`s are signed, i.e. they are in the range -128 to 127.  `Byte.valueOf` will only parse values in this range.  If you want to input numbers outside of this range, you can't use `Byte.valueOf`.

Despite the fact that `byte`s can't hold values greater than 127, they are still the correct type of value to pass to `InetAddress.getByAddress()`:

```
// Prints "/192.168.0.1"
System.out.println(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { (byte)192, (byte)168, 0, 1}));
```

One solution would be to use the parsing methods of a larger primitive type instead, and convert the result to a `byte`, for example:

```
ip[i] = Short.valueOf(keyboard.nextLine()).byteValue();
```

or

```
ip[i] = (byte)Short.parseShort(keyboard.nextLine());
```

As the range of a `short` is -32768 to 32767, this will work for all values in the range 0 to 255.

Both `Short.valueOf` and `Short.parseShort` do the same thing; they differ only in what type of value they return.  The former returns a `Short` object, which we get the `byte` value of by calling its `byteValue()` method.  The latter returns a `short` primitive, which we convert to a `byte` by casting it.

Note that this approach will also accept values outside the range 0 to 255, such as 1000 or -12345.  This may not be a problem, given that you're only using your program for your own educational purposes.

---

Incidentally, I initially struggled to compile your server code.  You have omitted the `import` statements and the declarations of some variables (possibly static fields).  As some of the variables had names beginning with capital letters, I was thinking to myself 'which package do I import `Keyboard` from?'  It turns out that `Keyboard` is actually a variable of type `Scanner`.  It was these capitalised  variable names, combined with missing variable/field declarations and import directives, which made for some rather confusing code.  Conventions may not be important for code you keep to yourself, but they are rather more important if you want others to read your code and not get confused by it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate response! I apologize for the sloppy coding and I will be sure to stick to conventions when I next need help (as is inevitable). I tried to include the class in its entirety but the class header and the imports didn't show up as code. Thank you for explaining what was wrong and how to fix it. I now have a better understanding.

Comment: @Nimmermehr: I suspect that the class header and imports weren't showing up as code because they weren't indented by 4 spaces whereas your method was.  To format a block of text as code, indent it by 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember that next time